# Storing session data in nodejs exprss

Tags: node.js, session

I have the following code that i am trying to store some data to a session variable:

```
//Capture IP geo-location info if it hasn't been set for this session
  app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    //Stuff to run once for each user session
    if (!req.session.runOnce){
     req.session.runOnce = true;
     if (!req.session.ipinfo || 1){
      //add user ip to sessions for use on who's online
      //if we're localhost, give it an 8.8.8.8 IP just so we can test something
      if (req.ip == '127.0.0.1'){ip = '8.8.8.8'; }else{ip = req.ip; }
     ip2location(ip, config.ipinfodb.apiKey, function(error, data){
       var ipData = JSON.parse(data);
       req.session.ipData = ipData;
      });

      next();
      }else{
        next();
      }
    }else{
      next();
    }
  });
```

The session.ipData is not being stored.  I can store it outside of the call to ip2location, and I can get session data inside of the call to ip2location.

Any ideas:
Thanks

Comment: In the code you don't check for `error`s. Are you postitive the data is arriving correctly?

Comment: Yes, ipData is getting the data correctly

Comment: You are setting req.session.ipData but testing for req.session.ipinfo

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that, but that still doesn't fix my issue.  It is not storing req.session.ipData.  I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The next() callback needs to be in the ip2Location call.